# Show $f: l^2 \rightarrow l^1$, defined by $f(\{x_n\}) = \{x_n/n\}$, is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, uniform-continuity

Let $f$ be a function defined  on   $\ell^{2}$ to $\ell^1$ by $f(x) =(x_n/ n)$. Show $f$ is uniformly continuous.

My attempt at the proof:
Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be sequences in $\ell^2$
Let $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = 6\varepsilon/\pi^2$.
Then $d(f((a_n),(b_n)))= \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty ({a_n-b_n\over n})^2\right)^{0.5} \le \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(a_n-b_n)^2\over n^2}\right)^{0.5} \le 
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(a_n-b_n)^2}\right)^{0.5} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty ({1 \over n^2})\right)^{0.5}$...
After some more typing, I end up with $|a_n-b_n|\cdot\delta$, which I then sub delta and get $\varepsilon$.

Does this show that f is uniformly continuous?

Comment: I think you may have formatting issues.

Comment: $f$ is uniform continuous, but your calculation is just not correct, starting from the first equality. What is $d(f(a_n), (b_n)))$?

Comment: @JohnMa I think it may be referring to the distance between f(an), and f(bn) in the l2 metric

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $X,Y$ are normed linear spaces and $T:X\to Y$ is a bounded linear map, then $T$ is not just uniformly continuous, it is Lipschitz, with Lipschitz constant equal to $\|T\|,$ the operator norm of $T.$ So we only need to show $f: l^2 \to l^1$ is a bounded linear operator. Wait! We don't even know yet that $\{a_n\}\in l^2 \implies f(\{a_n\})\in l^1.$ There is a very well known inequality that shows that. Once you have that, the fact that $f$ is bounded and linear is simple.